# Eclipse wouldn't build project because of a "build path pr0blem", but the source folder does exist

Tags: java, eclipse

This has been happening more and more often to us.
There is a source folder in our project. Frequently eclipse would insist that it can't build the project even though:

- the folder exists,
- the permissions allow for read/write,
- eclipse actually displays the folder in the "Package Explorer" view!

[image: screenshot]

There are no relevant entries in workspace log, nor in the console.
We have no good solution for this, it usually involves doing the following multiple times:

- refresh project
- close/open project
- clean project
- restart eclipse (with -clean)

It takes 20 minutes or so each time it happens.

My Eclipse is one of recent Kepler builds (4.3.2), running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Installed plugins:

```
  Atlassian Connector for Eclipse   3.2.2.v20130909 com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.feature.group   Atlassian
  Cucumber Eclipse Feature  0.0.11.201406031952 cucumber.eclipse.feature.feature.group  null
  EclEmma Java Code Coverage    2.3.1.201405111647  com.mountainminds.eclemma.feature.feature.group Mountainminds GmbH & Co. KG
  Eclipse SDK   4.3.2.M20140221-1700    org.eclipse.sdk.ide null
  Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.5.2.v201401062113-7H7IFizDxumVu0K6bjdPjXRkoz0FiUYMnSyT9PL org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JD-Eclipse Plug-in    0.1.5   jd.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group    Java Decompiler
  MoreUnit For Java 3.0.4   org.moreunit.feature.group  MoreUnit.org
  MoreUnit For Java: Mock Support   3.0.4   org.moreunit.mock.feature.group MoreUnit.org
  Mylyn Builds Connector: Hudson/Jenkins    1.1.2.v20140211-0100    org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group  Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Context Connector: Eclipse IDE  3.9.2.v20140211-0100    org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Context Connector: Java Development 3.9.2.v20140211-0100    org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Context Connector: Team Support 3.9.2.v20140211-0100    org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Task List   3.9.2.v20140211-0100    org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Task-Focused Interface  3.9.2.v20140211-0100    org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn WikiText    1.8.2.v20140211-0100    org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Native JavaHL 1.8 Implementation (Optional)   3.0.5.I20140122-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl18.feature.group  Polarion Software
  SonarQube Java Analyser   3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group SonarSource
  Subversive Revision Graph (Optional)  1.1.0.I20130619-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.revision.graph.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  Subversive SVN Integration for the Mylyn Project (Optional)   1.1.2.I20131116-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.mylyn.feature.group    Eclipse.org
  Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions (Optional)   1.1.0.I20130619-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.resource.ignore.rules.jdt.feature.group    Eclipse.org
  Subversive SVN Team Provider  1.1.3.I20140206-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group  Eclipse.org
```

Is there some known solution for this? Should I file a bug for eclipse?

Comment: Its a bug in eclipse.. You can't do anything about it..

Comment: Do you have a complete error message? A stacktrace? Something we could look at to understand what happens?

Comment: This happens with me also, so even i tend to do things like:- stop the server, clean the server, refresh the projects, republish projects to server, restart eclipse etc

Comment: @Jakub Bochenski Sounds weird. I have used eclipse for ages when developing java and haven't encountered this kind of problem. What os you use?

Comment: What version of Eclipse? I've seen behaviour like this on Kepler and Luna, but that's mainly around the classpath / source code when either running JUnit tests or running classes as Java apps (i.e. via the `main` method which Eclipse ignores for some reason, until restarted).

Comment: Do you have "build automatically" checked?

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer - I'll paste the config details in a sec but the eclipse config dump is rather lengthy

Comment: @cowls - after correcting my problem this time, I've checked that you can get similar symptoms with "Build automatically" unchecked. (So your comment is more helpful than one might expect).
However, running clean would normally start a build anyway, so it doesn't explain my situation.

Comment: @cowls - this just happened again to me, and I double checked that I had "build automatically" enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best workaround seems to be:

- delete problematic entry from eclipse build path dialog,
- restart eclipse
- close project
- revert .classpath file
- open project
- clean and auto build